# access header of current page in js

Tags: javascript, spring, spring-boot, header, http-headers

I'm redirecting to another url from my Spring Application. To do so I'm using this :

```
    @GetMapping
    public void method(HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse) {
        httpServletResponse.setHeader("Location", "http://localhost:3000/");
        httpServletResponse.setHeader("TOKEN","123");
        httpServletResponse.setStatus(302);
    }
```

Now I can redirect to any domain/path. But the biggest question is **how can I retrieve that token from client part ?**

I mean in my website(using plain JS only).

I had plan to use socket/rsocket, but now I think I would be better if I establish a connection only after user is verified or token is received in client.

I tried : `window.pageHeaders["TOKEN"]`, but it says : **Cannot read property 'TOKEN' of undefined**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of redirecting to `:3000`, redirect to `:3000/token`, call token from there, retrieve the token, then redirect to `:3000` or wherever you want.

Maybe PHP support the requested kind of way, just react doesn't or I can't. So let's just skip that, as the mentioned solution works, stick to this.